# Photoshop to HTML and spacer.gif issue

Tags: html, psd

Ive managed to output my psd to sliced html. Its an email signature.
It works fine on Thunderbird, Outlook and all other clients after some small modifications like editing code and adding line-height:0; border:none; border-collapse: collapse on every TD entry.

A strange issue occurs when it comes to mobile view. Spacers and photoshop slicers are visible for some reason. If i delete spacer.gif from the code, entire html is breaking up.

Please take a look at the screenshot, its quite helpful -> http://i.prntscr.com/bbe1eb504340451abd062ab275ccb6a2.png
If anyone knows how to make this working properly, i would be thankful.
The part of the code that includes the spacers is:

```
    <tr>
    <td style="line-height:0; border:none; border-collapse: collapse">
        <img src="http://domain.com/sign2016/sliced/spacer.gif" width="179" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td style="line-height:0; border:none; border-collapse: collapse">
        <img src="http://domain.com/sign2016/sliced/spacer.gif" width="125" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td style="line-height:0; border:none; border-collapse: collapse">
        <img src="http://domain.com/sign2016/sliced/spacer.gif" width="143" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td style="line-height:0; border:none; border-collapse: collapse">
        <img src="http://domain.com/sign2016/sliced/spacer.gif" width="40" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td style="line-height:0; border:none; border-collapse: collapse">
        <img src="http://domain.com/sign2016/sliced/spacer.gif" width="23" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td style="line-height:0; border:none; border-collapse: collapse">
        <img src="http://domain.com/sign2016/sliced/spacer.gif" width="23" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td style="line-height:0; border:none; border-collapse: collapse">
        <img src="http://domain.com/sign2016/sliced/spacer.gif" width="21" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td style="line-height:0; border:none; border-collapse: collapse">
        <img src="http://domain.com/sign2016/sliced/spacer.gif" width="27" height="1" alt=""></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Spacer GIF removal option in Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1cm2.png)

Here's an English version of what the previous poster said. To remove the spacer GIFs from the HTML export for sliced Photoshop files, go to the **Save for Web** window and then click the **"Optimize Menu"** icon at the top right then select the last item **"Edit Output Settings"**. Select **"Slices"** from the second dropdown menu, then finally under **"Spacer Cells"** select **"Never"**
Or just see the attached picture :) I hope this will be useful to someone.
Cheers!